# Paste PHP variable

Tags: php, variables

I'm working on a projects that uses the NEST API. I'm now trying to set the target temperature. The following code (hardcoding the value) is working. (15 degree celsius)

```
$nest->temperature_set(15);
```

But when I put a value in a variable it suddenly doesn't work. I checked if the variable is set and that is the case. It echos back the value that has been set, but i doesn't work in the procedure. Example:

```
$temptobeset = $_POST["newtemp"];
$nest->temperature_set($temptobeset);
```

Maybe someone can help me working out this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you putting the variable in quotes?!

Comment: Don't use quotes? `$nest->temperature_set($temptobeset);`

Comment: Remove the quote strings, so `$nest->temperature_set($temptobeset);` instead of `$nest->temperature_set('$temptobeset');`. When using the quotes, it will litterly set '$temotobeset', and not use the value within the variable.

Comment: I'm relative new to PHP. Just trying. With and without, but nothing worked :(

Comment: Define "nothing worked" better. What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I tried the advice that you gave me but it also didn't work. I'm expecting the same behavior as when I give the value hardcoded. (hardcoded works and my temperature adjusts, but using the same value in a variable it doesn't.  (The variable contains also 15).

Comment: What kind of library/SDK are you using there? Provide a link to the documentation at least!

Comment: For NEST this one: https://github.com/ablyler/nest-php-api

Comment: @CBroe maybe, but it's still not a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: Yeah, agreed on that one.

Comment: Make sure `$_POST["newtemp"]` actually is set to 15. Could also try to set `$temptobeset = 15;` and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the two codes (assuming `$_POST['newtemp']` is `'15'`), is that data in `$_POST` is always a string. Depending on how strict `temperature_set` is about types, you may need to cast your value to an integer:

```
$nest->temperature_set((int)$_POST['newtemp']);
```